# GitHub Desktop: "This file is empty"

Tags: git, github, github-desktop

The file `naaclhlt2016.tex` is not empty on the client or in the repository, however GitHub Desktop displays "This file is empty". What could explain this?

[image]

The file `naaclhlt2016.tex` is present on GitHub repository:

[image]

`git status`:

[image]

It creates conflict when I try to sync:

[image]

Comment: Is this a new file, not yet pushed?

Comment: @VonC The file naaclhlt2016.tex is present on GitHub repository.

Comment: Is it present in a different path? Is there any case difference anywhere in the path or name?

Comment: @VonC same path, same case.

Comment: What does a git status says, when using the command line?

Comment: @VonC git status thinks naaclhlt2016.tex has changed. I added the screenshot in the question. It looks like naaclhlt2016.tex appears in the list of changed files each time I compile the latex document.

Comment: If that document is generated, maybe it should not be versioned at all.

Comment: @VonC True, but compiling it shouldn't change it. Looking at the "date modified", you are [right](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/285530/11400) though. I guess that explains it.

Comment: That explains the modified status, but not "file is empty", unless GitHub Desktop is unable to display metadata changes, and consider it does not detect any file content change?

Comment: @VonC  I guess GitHub Desktop is unable to display metadata changes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After discussion, if the change of the tex file is only in term of metadata (and not actual file content change, after a latex recompilation), the GitHub Desktop might be unable to display any change.

Since it detects no change even though the git status list this file, it falls back to a "this file is empty" message.

Comment: That might be a bug or at least a surprising "feature" to report to GitHub support, and see if they think it is the expected response.

Comment: I will report, but first I will try to understand why compiling a tex file with Texmaker changes the “date modified” meta-information. I will let you know when I submit the report.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Did you get any feedback from gitHub support about this feature?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot whether I had submitted a report. I have just submitted one. Thanks for the follow-up.

Comment: "That may not be the intended behavior, but I am not sure. I have shared your feedback with our team for them to consider."

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt the suspense is killing me ;)

Comment: Any news on this?

Comment: @Varaquilex not on my side. Maybe the OP has more.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the @VonC response.

### To dissmiss this alert

Git desktop

1. unselect all changed files
2. select only the "this file is empty" files
3. try to commit
4. Git will display a commit error, saying that you can't do that. After closing the modal, Git should delete the files from the changes list.

Comment: I'd say this is the "solution" to this strange issue. Indeed trying to commit only these files results in an error, the commit is not done and the problem is gone. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm finding similar results when there is a mismatch between the `autoCRLF` setting (e.g. in `~/.gitconfig`) and the storage of line breaks in a text file. I have `.php` files that were downloaded on one (Windows) machine, zipped up and unzipped in an Apache folder, then I copied those to a cloned repo and it sometimes complains about every file as changed. The files stored on GitHub seem to have been stored with `CRLF` (they are larger).

I have been unable to get GitHub Desktop to process my modified files. I have tried a full fresh clone with `autoCRLF=true`, `autoCRLF=input`, and `autoCRLF=false`, and yet GitHub Desktop either reports the files as empty or every line changed, depending on the autoCRLF setting.

I believe it is entirely because they were stored on GitHub with the CRLFs in the files, and GitHub Desktop seems to assume that the `autoCRLF` governs (only) the checked out files, and won't compare *with* CRLFs on GitHub, even with `autoCRLF=false`.  They are byte-for-byte identical files, but they are LF-only, and it's either complaining every line has changed, or that the file is empty.

If I do a `git diff` on one of the files, in this case `feed.php`, I see:

`warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in API/events/feed.php.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.`